# socket send fails with 10054 error when trying to connect to different port on a separate thread

Tags: c, tcp

I'm a newbie in tcp protocol and websocket.

I've estalished a connection between server and client and created another thread to send the packets received from the server to a websocket. And my code looks as below.

This is the server side of a code

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char portStr[20];
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    MSG_PACKET packet;
    PQN_DATA_PACKET *ppacket;
    PACKET_HEADER *ppacket_header;
    queue<PQN_DATA_PACKET *> *pconnectionQ = new queue<PQN_DATA_PACKET *>();
    char ps8bufsend[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    char ps8bufrecv[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int packet_idx = 0;
    PQN_DATA_PACKET* pstpacket;
    int s8ack = 0;
    std::string filename, path;    
    int s32packetlen = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr = {0};
    struct sockaddr_in clnt_addr = {0};

    const char* ip = LOCAL_IP;
    SOCKET serv_sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    socklen_t clnt_addr_size;
    int clnt_sock;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    serv_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serv_sock == -1)
    {
        printf( "socket() Error..Error --> Code %d ", WSAGetLastError() );
        error_handling("socket error");
    }
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(CLIENT_PORT_NUMBER);
    if(bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1)
    {
        printf( "bind() Error..Error --> Code %d ", WSAGetLastError() );
        error_handling("bind error");
    }
    if(listen(serv_sock, 5) == -1)
    {
        printf( "listen() Error..Error --> Code %d ", WSAGetLastError() );
        error_handling("listen error");
    }
    clnt_addr_size = sizeof(clnt_addr);
    clnt_sock = accept(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_addr, &clnt_addr_size);
    if(clnt_sock == -1)
    {
        printf( "accept() Error..Error --> Code %d ", WSAGetLastError() );
        error_handling("accept error");
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen( argv[1], "r+");
    FILE *fpout = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    ProcessFile(fp);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (i == ORDER_TIME_SETTING)
        {
            MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET;
            s32packetlen = sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET);           
            if (clnt_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            
            iResult = recv(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, s32packetlen, 0);        
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("recv failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());               
                return -1;
            }
            if (ps8ptr->header.msg_id != MSG_PDDAU_INFO_ID && ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_REQUEST_TYPE)
            {
                printf("Time setting failed\n");
                return -1;
            }
            if(!ps8ptr->time_enable)
            {
                printf("Time is disabled!\n");
                return -1;
            }
            ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_REQUEST_ACK_TYPE;
           
            iResult = send(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET), 0);   
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("send failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());                               
                return -1;
            }        
        }
        else if (i == ORDER_PDDAU_INFO)
        {
            MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET;    
            iResult = recv(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET), 0);        
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("recv failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());                               
                return -1;
            }
            if (ps8ptr->header.msg_id != MSG_PDDAU_INFO_ID && ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_READ_INFO_TYPE)
            {
                printf("PDDAU Info Setting failed\n");
                return -1;                
            }        
            ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_READ_INFO_RESPONSE_TYPE;
         
            iResult = send(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET), 0);   
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("send failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());                               
                return -1;
            }                
        }
        else if (i == ORDER_RF_INFO)
        {
            MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET;
            iResult = recv(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET), 0);        
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("recv failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());                                               
                return -1;
            }
            if (ps8ptr->header.msg_id != MSG_RF_INFO_ID && ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_READ_INFO_TYPE)
            {
                printf("PDDAU Info Setting failed\n");
                return -1;                            
            }
            ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_READ_INFO_RESPONSE_TYPE;           
            iResult = send(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET), 0);   
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("send failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());                                              
                return -1;
            }                     
        }
        else if(i == ORDER_PD_DATA)
        {
            printf("Yo 1\n");
            MSG_PD_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PD_PACKET;
            iResult = recv(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0); 
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("recv failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());                                                               
                return -1;
            }
            if (ps8ptr->header.msg_id != MSG_PD_START_ID && ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_REQUEST_TYPE)
            {
                printf("PDDAU Info Setting failed\n");
                return -1;                            
            }               
            ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_REQUEST_ACK_TYPE;              
            iResult = send(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0);   
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("send failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());                                                              
                return -1;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            MSG_PD_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PD_PACKET;
            printf("Yo 2\n");
            iResult = recv(clnt_sock, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0);    
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                return -1;
            } 
            if(ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_REQUEST_TYPE || ps8ptr->header.msg_id != MSG_PD_START_ID)
            {
                printf("PD Sending failed\n");
                return -1;
            }
            ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_REQUEST_ACK_TYPE;

            iResult = send(clnt_sock, (char*) ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0);   
            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                printf("Yo 2\n");
                fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                return -1;
            }             

            while(fgets(ps8bufsend, ONE_CYCLE, fpout) != NULL)
            {
                memset(ps8ptr->data,0,ONE_CYCLE);
                memcpy(ps8ptr->data, ps8bufsend, ONE_CYCLE);                
                boost::asio::io_context io;
                boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds(83));  

                packet_idx++;                     
                ps8ptr->header.msg_id = MSG_PD_SEND_ID;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_SEND_TYPE;    
                printf("Yo 3\n");
                s8ack = send(clnt_sock,(char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET),0);
                printf("Yo 4\n");
                if (s8ack == -1)
                {
                    printf("Yo 5\n");
                    //fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    printf("send failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());                                                                  
                    return -1;
                }
```

This is my client side of the code.

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PQN_DATA_PACKET* pstpacket;
    //int serv_sock;
    SOCKET serv_sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    int clnt_sock;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int nErrorStatus;
    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    const char* ip = LOCAL_IP;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr = {0};
    struct sockaddr_in clnt_addr = {0};
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    socklen_t clnt_addr_size;
    char buff[255];
    int iResult;
    queue<PQN_DATA_PACKET *> *pconnectionQ = new queue<PQN_DATA_PACKET *>();
    DWORD RunWebServerThreadID;
    nErrorStatus = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

    PACKET_HEADER *ppacket_header;
    ppacket_header = new PACKET_HEADER;
    std::fstream datfile;
    std::string filename, path;   
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    char ps8bufsend[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    char ps8bufrecv[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];     
    int order[] = {ORDER_TIME_SETTING, ORDER_PDDAU_INFO, ORDER_RF_INFO, ORDER_PD_DATA};
    int s32packetlen = 0;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    iResult = getaddrinfo(LOCAL_IP, "8081", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
    {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
                            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    HANDLE t2 = CreateThread(0, 0, RunWebServerThread, pconnectionQ, 0, &RunWebServerThreadID);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //while(1)
        //{
            if(i == ORDER_TIME_SETTING)
            {
                MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_id = MSG_PDDAU_INFO_ID;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_REQUEST_TYPE;
                ps8ptr->time_enable = 0x01;
                s32packetlen = sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET);
   
                printf("ConnectSocket=%i\n", ConnectSocket);           
                iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)ps8ptr, s32packetlen, 0);   
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                } 
                memset(ps8ptr, 0, s32packetlen);
                iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char*)ps8ptr, s32packetlen, 0);        
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                } 
                printf("recv result : %d\n",iResult);
                printf("header msg_id : %d\n", ps8ptr->header.msg_id);
                if (ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_REQUEST_ACK_TYPE)
                {
                    printf("Time setting failed\n");
                    return -1;     
                }     
                delete ps8ptr;
                ps8ptr = NULL;
            }
            else if(i == ORDER_PDDAU_INFO)
            {
                MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_id = MSG_PDDAU_INFO_ID;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_READ_INFO_TYPE;
              
                iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET), 0);   
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                } 
                memset(ps8ptr, 0, sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET));
                iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET), 0);        
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                } 
                if (ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_READ_INFO_RESPONSE_TYPE)
                {
                    printf("PDDAU Info Setting failed\n");
                    return -1;     
                }      
                delete ps8ptr;
                ps8ptr = NULL;
            }            
            else if(i == ORDER_RF_INFO)
            {
                MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_id = MSG_RF_INFO_ID;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_READ_INFO_TYPE;
                iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*) ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET), 0);   
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                }                 
                memset(ps8ptr, 0, sizeof(MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET));
                iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_RF_INFO_PACKET), 0);        
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                } 
                if (ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_READ_INFO_RESPONSE_TYPE)
                {
                    printf("RF Info Setting  failed\n");
                    return -1;     
                }
                delete ps8ptr;
            }
            else if(i == ORDER_PD_DATA)
            {
                MSG_PD_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PD_PACKET;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_id = MSG_PD_START_ID;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_REQUEST_TYPE;
                  
                iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*) ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0);   
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                }                 
                memset(ps8ptr, 0, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET));
                iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0);        
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                } 
                if (ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_REQUEST_ACK_TYPE)
                {
                    printf("RF Info Setting  failed\n");
                    return -1;     
                }  
                delete ps8ptr;
            }
            else
            {
                MSG_PD_PACKET *ps8ptr = new MSG_PD_PACKET;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_id = MSG_PD_START_ID;
                ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_REQUEST_TYPE;
                ps8ptr->header.body_len = sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET); 
                ps8ptr->ch_idx = 1;     
                printf("Error?\n");
                iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*) ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0);   
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                }             
                memset(ps8ptr, 0, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET));
                iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0);        
                if (iResult == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    return -1;
                } 
                if (ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_REQUEST_ACK_TYPE)
                {
                    printf("RF Info Setting  failed\n");
                    return -1;     
                }  

                while(1)
                {
                    MSG_PD_PACKET *ps8data = new MSG_PD_PACKET;
                    printf("Error 2?\n");
                    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char*)ps8ptr, sizeof(MSG_PD_PACKET), 0);        
                    if (iResult == -1)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                        return -1;
                    } 
                    if(ps8ptr->header.msg_type != MSG_SEND_TYPE || ps8ptr->header.msg_id != MSG_PD_SEND_ID)
                    {
                        printf("PD Sending failed. type : %x, id : %x\n", ps8ptr->header.msg_type, ps8ptr->header.msg_id);
                        return -1;
                    }           

                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(queue_mutex2);
                    (*pconnectionQ).push(pstpacket);
```

And here is the thread function I run on the client side.

```
DWORD WINAPI RunWebServerThread(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    //server srv;
    //srv.run(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v6(), SERVER_PORT_NUMBER), 1);
    
    int threads(1);
    net::io_context ioc{ threads };

    queue<PQN_DATA_PACKET *> *pconnectionQ = (queue<PQN_DATA_PACKET *> *)lpParameter;    
    auto const address = net::ip::make_address(LOCAL_IP);
    // Create and launch a listening port
    std::make_shared<listener>(ioc, tcp::endpoint{ address, SERVER_PORT_NUMBER }, pconnectionQ)->run();
    // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    v.reserve(threads - 1);
    for (auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
        v.emplace_back(
            [&ioc]
            {
                ioc.run();
            });
    ioc.run();    
    
}
```

As you can see there is no correlation between the port used in the thread function and main socket.

However, here is the output I've got on the server side once I connect frontend websocket.

```
Yo 3
Yo 4
Yo 3
Yo 4
Yo 5
send failed with error: 10054
```

Can anyone point out the possible problem with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with boost (it doesn't even really use any C++)? Or websockets? And you didn't even tag with [tag:c]

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I've solved the problem myself.
The reason the connection was closed is because I've been using the wrong type of data packet. It was supposed to be something else other than PQN_DATA_PACKET.
Thus, the thread function died and affected the regular connection since it couldn't handle the right type of the packet.

It was an amateur mistake in my part..

Thanks everyone for focusing on my problem.